# URL Fetch AssertionError: 2

Tags: google-app-engine

When using the asynchronous URL Fetch I get intermittent errors like this:

For 300 fetches I'm getting about 20 of theses.  Am I doing something wrong?  Or is this a bug?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~culturemap-bulkmail/1.368407357562484358/bulkmail/views.py", line 83, in mailer
    emailer.send(email, context)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~culturemap-bulkmail/1.368407357562484358/bulkmail/mailers/amazon.py", line 91, in send
    self.connection.send(email, msg.message().as_string())
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~culturemap-bulkmail/1.368407357562484358/bulkmail/mailers/amazon.py", line 49, in send
    headers=self.headers,
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/urlfetch.py", line 339, in make_fetch_call
    rpc.make_call('Fetch', request, response, _get_fetch_result, allow_truncated)
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 519, in make_call
    assert self.__rpc.state == apiproxy_rpc.RPC.IDLE, repr(self.state)
AssertionError: 2
```

in **init**:

```
self.fetcher = urlfetch.create_rpc(deadline=60)
```

in method that gets called several times:
also line that errors out:

```
fetch = urlfetch.make_fetch_call(
  self.fetcher,
  'https://email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/',
  payload=form_data,
  method=urlfetch.POST,
  headers=self.headers,
)
```

I guess I should create a new rpc instead of reusing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show some of your code, from the error it looks like you're reusing an existing active RPC object.

Comment: ok updated with my code.  I think your right, I didn't notice in the examples to always create a new RPC.